# The way to detect changes automatically in dynamically loaded component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-changedetection, angular-dynamic-components

I have a component dynamically loaded into `<ng-template>`.

Here is an example code:

Html:

```html
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

TS:

```js
@ViewChild('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef })
dynamic: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private injector: Injector
) {}

async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const exampleModule = await import(PATH_TO_A_MODULE_TO_BE_LOADED).then(m => m.ExampleModule);
    const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(exampleModule);
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.resolveComponent();
    const ref = container.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);
}
```

The above code will load a component in `ExampleModule` dynamically.

The problem is that the component doesn't detect its changes automatically.

So I have to call `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` everytime something changed in the component.

I'd like to know if there is a way to let the component detect changes automatically without using the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, so it's necessary to use the changeDetectorRef? is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Contain the ng-template inside the div

```
<div #dynamic>
  <ng-template></ng-template>
</div>
```

Then use ngAfterViewInit()
Inside that emit the textContent of the ViewChild #dynamic

Answer (score -1):

You need to register it in `ApplicationRef`
https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#attachview

Inject `ApplicationRef` in your service, and call its `attachView` method

```js
@ViewChild('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef })
dynamic: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private injector: Injector,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef

) {}

async ngAfterViewInit() {
    const exampleModule = await import(PATH_TO_A_MODULE_TO_BE_LOADED).then(m => m.ExampleModule);
    const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(exampleModule);
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.resolveComponent();
    const ref = container.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);
    this.appRef.attachView(ref);  // NOTE ref might not be the right type, it needs to be a view Ref and I can't check what type it actually is.  
}
```

Comment: it seems not working.. `ref` is a component instance there.

Comment: `This will throw if the view is already attached to a ViewContainer.` - description from the link. My component is appended to `ViewContainer`